Custom SwiftUI Controls with Generic Binding
My goal is to create a custom control in SwiftUI that accepts a binding to a generic value without declaring the control's type itself as generic on that type.
For example, I'm really interested to figure out how the SwiftUI Slider accepts a binding to BinaryFloatingPoint in its initializers without declaring the Slider as generic on BinaryFloatingPoint.
Type erasure or conversion is my best guess so far, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work yet.
struct MyCustomControl: View {
    @Binding private var value: any BinaryFloatingPoint

    var body: some View {
        // ...
    }

    init<V: BinaryFloatingPoint>(value: Binding<V>) {
        self._value = value // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<V>' to type 'Binding<any BinaryFloatingPoint>'
    }
}

The emitted error makes sense. I'm just not sure how to get around it.

But Gauge doesn’t take a Binding as argument so that example is a bit misleading

SwiftUI doesn't play well with existentials, you have to use concrete types. Your @Binding using existentials and your init uses concrete types you can alway make the struct use concrete.

@JoakimDanielson you're right. Switched the example to Slider.

You should make the whole type generic, not just the init
struct MyCustomControl<V: BinaryFloatingPoint>: View {
    @Binding private var value: V

    var body: some View {
        //…
    }

    init(value: Binding<V>) {
        self._value = value 
    }
}

